# Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase' etc flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase

I'm trying to run the app on iOS (simulator and real device) for days and I keep getting this error I tried to delete all pod folders / files and reinstall pods - cache repair - updates and it doesn't work

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase'
/Users/yomna/apps/Intros/intros_dating/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap:0:7

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'ObjectiveC'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:113:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'os_object'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:62:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'os_object'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h:18:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Dispatch'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:19:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:5:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:27:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:17:9
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You have to delete firebase-ios-sdk from Runner-> Packages installer-> firebase-ios-sdk.

Comment: Please don't post an answer which just points to a different Stack Overflow question. Once you earn enough reputation, you will be able to leave comments. Until then, please restrict your engagement with the site to interactions which are allowed at your current privilege level, that is, asking questions, posting actual answers, and suggesting edits to posts.